# Passing data between UIViewControllers controlled by UITabBarController in Swift 5

Tags: swift

I've got a TabBarViewController controlling 5 UIViewControllers.
I'm trying to pass data (a user object in particular) from one UIViewController.
What I'm currently doing is to set the user property in the TabBar Controller from within one of the UIViewControllers (HomeScreen) like so:

```swift
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

    let apiService = APIService()
    var user: User?
    var parentController: TabBarController?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let token = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "authtoken")!
        self.apiService.getUserFromAuthtoken(token: token, completion: {result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let user):
                self.user = user
                self.parentController = self.tabBarController as? TabBarController
                self.parentController?.user = user
                print("EMAIL-HOME-SCREEN: ", user.email)
            case .failure(let error):
                print("An error occured \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Then, after navigation, I'm trying to access the TabBarView's user property from another UIViewController (CoopOverview) like so:

```swift
class CoopOverviewViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var CampaignBrandSliderBackground: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var CampaignCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var CampaignBrandSlider: UISegmentedControl!
    var user: User?
    var parentController: TabBarController?


    @IBOutlet weak var foo: UIView!


    let campaignImages: [UIImage] = [UIImage(named: "icon-black")!,UIImage(named: "icon-white")!,UIImage(named: "icon-black")!,UIImage(named: "icon-white")!]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.parentController = self.tabBarController as? TabBarController
        self.user = self.parentController?.user
        print("EMAIL-COOP-SCREEN: ", user!.email)
        ...
}
```

Is this a good approach or is there a more elegant way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would discourage the tight coupling between the `TabBarController` and each of its children. The children should not be relying on their parent’s internal implementation details.

Why’s that a problem? What if you later change the parent to a page view controller later? Or some other custom container view controller? You don’t want to have to go into all these children to fix that. Children should rely upon abstractions and not rely upon implementation details of their parent.

There are two solutions:

1. Avoid tight coupling of classes via protocol. For example,

   - you might have a `UserProvider` or `UserDataSource` protocol that exposes a property or method to retrieve the current user from the source of truth;
   - the tab bar controller (or it’s view model) can conform to that protocol;
   - the children then use this protocol, not `UITabBarController` type, to retrieve the `User`; and
   - when the tab bar controller selects a child, it can supply a reference to itself as this protocol type.

   Now, you have the basic structure that your original pattern had, but without the tight coupling between our classes.
2. Going a step further, use dependency injection, where the parent injects whatever the child needs.

   So, rather than having the children reach back into the parent (via a protocol) to retrieve the `User`, the other approach is to have a `User` property in all the children and have the parent inject it into the relevant children.

   So you might have a protocol for children that have a settable `User` property. Then the tab bar controller would, for any children that conform to that protocol, supply a copy of the `User`. Again, using protocols keeps these loosely coupled.

Both of these patterns avoid tight coupling between our classes.

Comment: Thank you so much for your in-depth feedback!!